# Facebook Api v2.1 - Link Delete not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, http-delete, facebook-feed

I'm using Facebook Api v2.1 and i came across a weird situation.

I'm creating a new feed using /{UserId}/feed with POST. So far so good.
I can even delete that post with /{PostId} and DELETE method

The problem is when i create a feed with a link and then try to delete it with /{LinkId} (and DELETE method)

Its returns the following error: 
message":"(#200) This post wasn't created by the application"

How can this be? I already checked the publish_actions permissions and you can be 100% sure i'm the one posting because the post DELETE works.

Any ideas? 
Thnks in advance

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding the question. I've tried it with the Graph API explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/ But for me the PostId or the LinkId is exactly the same, if you publish using /{UserId}/feed you get always the PostId (whether with link or without it) and I'm always able to delete it. How are you getting the linkId?

Comment: "linkid" is the way facebook represents ids from feeds/posts of "link" type.
The problem is not the id itself, the problem is deleting a feed with DELETE method when the feed is of link type. Tried today on the explorer and it gives me the same error. Seems like a facebook api bug but i found nothing documented.

Comment: What I'm saying is that I've created a post with link type and then I've tried to delete it and I've do it successfully, of course using the Graph API explorer with the same token for both. I can not reproduce your error.

Answer (score 0):

You can only delete posts if:

1. Posted by your same app, **using the user access token** from the user that posted them
2. On the timeline of a page you're administering, using the Page access token for that page.

It sounds like you're not doing either of those - the error message is likely correct.

You can likely check that if it is working in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/.

1. Get access token of user for your app
2. Post through feed
3. Delete with link id.

I have just tested it, it works fine.

**Update:**

One thing I noticed is, when we create post with link (only {post_id}), then id generated is not same as when we generate with post ({app_id}_{post_id}). I believe delete for /links is not supported. But delete for '/feed` with link field or not is supported.

Comment: Then why is Post DELETE successful and Link DELETE is not?

Comment: One thing I noticed is, when we create post with link (only {post_id}), then id generated is not same as when we generate with post ({app_id}_{post_id}). I believe delete for `/links` is not supported. But delete for '/feed` with link field or not is supported.

Comment: @FranciscoAfonso: I have checked it. But I think it somehow not work as per documentation or some layer is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/35204907/1861769):

> Maybe you were suffering a bug (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1671530079772375/) which is fixed now.
>
> If you published a post with a link through an app being in development mode, this post wasn't credited to your app [bug] so, if you tried to delete it, you couldn't because Facebook only allows to delete posts published by your app.