# Facebook Graph API v2.5 - Impossible to delete post created with a link

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook Graph API v2.5 to publish and delete posts from user's profiles.
I'm using Postman (Chrome extension) to test my REST calls.

Case 1) When all actually works:
- I do a POST request to "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/MY_USER_ID/feed", with params "access_token" and "message"
- The API returns me the created post ID, let's say "108373569531356_138530589848987"
- Then I do a DELETE request to "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/108373569531356_138530589848987", with params "access_token".
- My message I successfully removed from user's profile

Case 2) My issue, it does not work as expected
- I do the same POST request as previous, but I add an extra "link" parameter.
- The API returns me the created post ID.
- Then when I try to delete this post using DELETE request, the Facebook API throws me an error: "message": "(#100) This post could not be loaded"

One thing I noticed, is that first request seems to create me a Facebook "post", but the second one seems to create a "link".
I used the v2.3 API get/post_id to compare both posts, they are pretty much different.

So, why can't I delete a "link" element, the Facebook documentation does not tell anything about it.

Many thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you were suffering a bug (https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1671530079772375/) which is fixed now.

If you published a post with a link through an app being in development mode, this post wasn't credited to your app [bug] so, if you tried to delete it, you couldn't because Facebook only allows to delete posts published by your app.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I'll have a look at that later :)